# How to update a table in MYSQL using JavaGUI?

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

So I have a java GUI that can let the user to enter a name email etc. It will also let the user to update and delete. In the GUI you can see a `JTextField`, 5 buttons for: save, delete, update, cancel and exit. All of the buttons and their `actionListener` works perfectly fine. But the Update is not working properly, a `JOptionPane` will show saying "Record Updated" but when you look at the database nothing happens. Here is my code for **Update** button :

```
 update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String num = IDNumber.getText();
                try {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/edp", "root", "");
                    String query = "UPDATE usersample SET LastName = ?, FirstName = ?, EMAIL=?, UserName = ?, userPass = sha1(?) where UserID = ?";
                    PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

                    pst.setString(1, num);
                    pst.setString(2, first.getText());
                    pst.setString(3, last.getText());
                    pst.setString(4, email.getText());
                    pst.setString(5, userName.getText());
                    pst.setString(6, password.getText());

                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");
                    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tb1.getModel();
                    list(); // this will show an supposedly 'UPDATED' table in my JTable that are visible in my JAVA GUI
                    layas(); // this will set all the text in my JtextField to empty 
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your `setString` fields do not correspond with the order of the parameters in the prepared statement. Also, have got autocommit turned on in mysql ?

Comment: what is  autocommit ? and this is actually connected to my mysql they all work fine. Only the update thing is not okay